# go get mongo-go-driver crashes in Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, go, dockerfile

I have a little problem with my Go service. I'm new to Go and I just want to dockerize a little service that just connect to a mongodb instance.

My code works fine locally. So here is my Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM golang:alpine AS build-env
RUN apk add --no-cache git
ADD . .

RUN go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver    
RUN go build -o mongotest

# final stage
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env ./go/mongotest .

RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./mongotest"]
```

When I build it, I have this error message :

```
Step 6/18 : RUN go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
 ---> Running in 4c45c601800d
Fetching https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver.git"} at https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver?go-get=1
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver (download)
package go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver: no Go files in /go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver
The command '/bin/sh -c go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

`no Go files in /go/src` ... ok, what can I do with that?

The strange thing is that if I replace

`RUN go get -d -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver`

by

`RUN go get -d -u github.com/gorilla/mux`

it works!

Is there a problem with mongo driver repo?

Comment: I saw here : https://medium.com/dev-howto/how-to-use-go-with-mongodb-using-official-mongodb-go-driver-76c1628dae1e that the `no Go files in` is an expected output. So I modified the RUN like this :

RUN go get -d -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver; exit 0

But it does not seem to be a good practice ...

Comment: Did you try to instead of `RUN go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver` run `RUN go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) repository recommend to use this command :

```sh
dep ensure -add "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@~1.0.0"
```

and you can see golang package url:
`go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`

Try:

```
RUN go get -v -u go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```